# Unknown external links to https://simtelnet.com/mudstealthy.php?option=0

Tags: html, hyperlink

I recently crawled my website for an audit and found an unknown external link:

https://simtelnet.com/mudstealthy.php?option=0

By the name it seems like a "shady" link. Does anyone know what is this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found out what this is.

it's the "challenge" question for the cloudflare check.